# Rust trait bounds for integral types

Tags: rust, traits, bounds

Suppose I have my own type as a tuple struct

```rust
struct MyType(u8);
```

And would like to implement the `From` trait for the other integral types in a generic way, like

```rust
impl From<T> for MyType {
    fn from(num: T) -> Self {
        MyType((num & 0xff) as u8)
    }
}
```

Rust does not allow this because generic types `T` do not have the `as` operator. How can I constrain `T` to the integral types so that `as` can be used? something along the lines of

```rust
impl From<T: Integral> for MyType {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`num-traits`](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) crate.

[`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.12/num_traits/int/trait.PrimInt.html) is the relevant trait, which extends [`NumCast`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.12/num_traits/cast/trait.NumCast.html) which allows conversion between the primitive numeric types.

EDIT: Here's an example implementation.  It's a bit ugly because many of the relevant conversions return `Option`, since they don't know ahead of time that the values are in range.

```
impl<T: PrimInt> From<T> for MyType {
    fn from(num: T) -> Self {
        let clamped = num & T::from(0xFFu8).unwrap();
        Self(clamped.to_u8().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to specifically reference the example they've given; where all integers implement `From<u8>`, and therefore `0xFF` can be converted to them.

Comment: I don't quite like the `T::from` that returns an `Option`. In the standard  `std::convert::From` it is stated that "Note: This trait must not fail. If the conversion can fail, use TryFrom.". This seems to go against that idea. But thanks for pointing to num-traits.

Comment: @Miguel This `from()` method is not from the `From` trait, rather it's a method on `NumCast` with the same name.  It is unfortunate that `from::<u8>` returns an option, but it makes sense for things like converting `u64` to `u32`.

Comment: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-add-explicitly-named-numeric-conversion-apis/11395 would be a step in the right direction I think, with the `IntToInt` trait and `wrapping_to()`